# Como agrupar correctamente dos columnas en una matriz

Tags: matriz, powerbi

Estoy en la creación de una matriz en Power BI en la que quisiera agrupar la columna `PRODUCT` por `NAME` de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando realizar lo mismo en una matriz en Power BI pero no logro conseguirlo, intento trasladar las columnas al apartado de Filas, pero estas solo me quedan de manera escalonada así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo intente también cambiando la columna `PRODUCT` al apartado de Columnas pero aun así tampoco logro conseguirlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si hay manera de agrupar las columnas como se encuentra en la primera imagen que les compartí, agradezco quien me pueda dar una orientación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder visualizarlo como quieres necesitas modificar el diseño de las filas e incluir ambas columnas como filas (como has hecho en tu primer ejemplo).

Tienes que desmarcar el selector que activa el "Diseño escalonado" que viene activado por defecto:

[image: Matriz - Diseño - Diseño escalonado]

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.